# Homeomorphism mapping arbitrary points to arbitrary points in n dimensions

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions

Take $k$ arbitrary points in $n$ dimensional space.  Is there always a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ mapping those $k$ points to another arbitrary set of $k$ points?  If so, are there methods of finding $f$?  If not, what's the largest $k$ such that this is true?

Comment: For $n=1$, there's always a polynomial, and Lagrange interpolation finds it. I bet you can find a generalization of Lagrange interpolation to higher dimensions.

Comment: Right...so that gives a continuous mapping, but unless I'm missing something that's not always a homeomorphism.

Comment: So for $n=1$ it's clear that the largest $k$ is $2$.

Comment: I missed that, but you are quite right that for $n=1$ the largest $k$ is 2. That is, if you specify for each of the $k$ points in the domain which of the $k$ points in the codomain is to be its image. But if you only insist the one set gets mapped to the other, and you don't care which point in the one gets mapped to which point in the other, then $k$ can be arbitrarily large (for $n=1$).

Comment: I found this on page 9 of Alpern and Prasad, Typical Dynamics of Volume Preserving Homeomorphisms: Let $F$ be a finite set in the interior $X$ of the $n$-cube. Then any embedding of $F$ into the $n$-cube can be extended to a volume-preserving homeomorphism of the $n$-cube. A bit of a worry, since this is false for $n=1$, but maybe if you get the book (I can only see bits of it on Google) you'll find that somewhere the authors require $n\ge2$.